# Generically iterating over accessors of a product type

Tags: haskell, generics, generics-sop

I've written the following function using [`generics-sop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop). What it does, is given a value of a product type, goes through all it's members, applies a function to all those members, and spits out a list of the results:

```
import Generics.SOP qualified as SOP
import Generics.SOP hiding (Generic)

productToList :: forall c a t xs. (
  IsProductType a xs, 
  SOP.Generic a, 
  ProductCode a ~ xs, 
  All c xs
  ) 
  => (forall b. c b => b -> t) -> a -> [t]
productToList f = hcollapse . hcmap (Proxy :: Proxy c) (mapIK f) . productTypeFrom
```

Here's some example usage:

```
import Generics.SOP qualified as SOP
import Generics.SOP hiding (Generic)

data MyNums = MyNums { anInt :: Int, anInteger :: Integer, aFloat :: Float }
  deriving stock Generic
  deriving anyclass SOP.Generic

class (Eq a, Num a) => EqNum a 
instance (Eq a, Num a) => EqNum a 

c = MyNums { anInt = 0, anInteger = 5, aFloat = 7.2 }

f :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
f x = x == 0

y :: [Bool]
y = genericProductToList @EqNum f c
```

This will output the list `[True, False, False]`.

So far so good. But with some code I'm trying to make generic now, the signature I need is slightly different. Instead of:

```
productToList          :: ... => (forall b. c b => b -> t) -> a -> [t]
```

I want

```
productAccessorsToList :: ... => (forall b. c b => (a -> b) -> t) -> [t]
```

Basically instead of passing a value of a structure and iterating over the members, in this case don't have a value, but I want to iterate over the accessors functions of a type.

I've basically moved the `a` from outside the `forall` to inside the `forall`.

What is an implementation of `productAccessorsToList`?

Comment: Well, one way of doing it might involve using productToList as an accessor itself...

Comment: Some random comments: the constraint `ProductCode a ~ xs` is redundant as it is implied by `IsProductType a xs`. And the definition of `EqNum` is unnecessary as you can write ``Eq `And` Num``

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental functionality is contained in `projections`. Manipulate that.

```
projectionsToList ::
  forall c a t xs.
  ( IsProductType a xs
  , SOP.Generic a
  , ProductCode a ~ xs
  , All c xs
  )
 => (forall b. c b => (a -> b) -> t)
 -> [t]
projectionsToList f =
    hcollapse @_ @_ @NP @xs
  $ hcmap (Proxy @c) adjust (projections @_ @I)
  where
    adjust :: forall x. c x => (K (NP I xs) -.-> I) x -> K t x
    adjust p = K $ f $ unI . apFn p . K . productTypeFrom
```

You can recover `productToList` from this, but I don't believe it works the other way around

```
productToList' ::
   forall c a t xs.
   ( IsProductType a xs
   , SOP.Generic a
   , ProductCode a ~ xs
   , All c xs
   ) 
  => (forall b. c b => b -> t)
  -> a -> [t]
productToList' f x = projectionsToList @c @a (f . ($ x))
-- would probably be slower than productToList
```