Generically combining profunctors
I'm looking to create a function like this:
recordSelectorToData :: forall c a f xs. 
  (All c xs, IsProductType a xs, Applicative f) => 
  (forall b. c b => (a -> b) -> f b) -> f a

Where All and IsProductType are from generics-sop.
The (a -> b) argument should be the record selector for the particular field we're dealing with. Perhaps this specialisation of the function makes things clearer:
profunctorToData :: forall c a p xs. 
  (All c xs, IsProductType a xs, Profunctor p, Applicative (p a)) =>
  (forall b. c b => p b b) -> p a a
profunctorToData x = recordSelectorToData @c (`lmap` x)

This says basically:

If we have a product type AND
All of the elements are of constraint c AND
We have make a Profunctor for all the elements AND
The Profunctor is Applicative in it's last value

THEN

We can create a Profunctor that combines all the profunctors of all the elements.

Why do I want to do this? autodocodec is a library for generating ToJSON, FromJSON and ToSchema (i.e. Swagger documentation) instances in one definition. The library doesn't depend on profunctor, it's main datatype, Codec, basically is a Profunctor, as it is a Functor, Applicative, and has a function lmapCodec, which means Codec is trivially definable as a Profunctor.
autodocodec instances are defined using applicative notation like the following:
data Example = Example
  { exampleText :: !Text,
    exampleBool :: !Bool
  }
instance HasCodec Example where
  codec =
    object "Example" $
      Example
        <$> requiredField "text" .= exampleText
        <*> requiredField "bool" .= exampleBool

note, above, .= is actually just another name for lmapCodec.
Whilst there are some datatypes in my app I just manually define the codec like above, there are others where I use the following approach:
I have definitions like this:
data MyRecord1 = MyRecord1 
{ firstName :: FirstName
, lastName :: LastName
} deriving stock (Generic)

And a class like the following:
class HasCodec a => FieldName a where
  fieldName :: Text

instance FieldName FirstName where
  fieldName = "firstname"

instance FieldName LastName where
  -- The field names don't always match the source code.
  fieldName = "sirname" 

Then I can write the function:
makeObjectCodec :: (HasCodec b, FieldName b) => (a -> b) -> Object a b
makeObjectCodec f = requiredField (fieldName @b) .= f

And with this, I should be able to write:
myRecord1Codec :: ObjectCodec MyRecord1 MyRecord1
myRecord1Codec = recordSelectorToData @FieldName makeObjectCodec

I have spent some time staring at generics-sop, but I'm unsure how to get the record selectors out as functions I can use. Any help appreciated.
Edit:
Searching through StackOverflow, I've realised I must have gone down a path similar to this before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76024467/525980
This doesn't do exactly what I want, but it's closer, and in particular, it highlights I need to use projections.
